# Grouping list of dict based on key

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

i have some stopper to grouping my list of dict data :

**My Data :**

```
[
  { day: 1, type: "EL", total: 1 },
  { day: 2, type: "EL", total: 3 },
  { day: 1, type: "DL", total: 2 },
  { day: 1, type: "AV", total: 4 },
  { day: 9, type: "CD", total: 2 },
]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[
    {type: "EL", "1": 1, "2": 3},
    {type: "DL", "1": 2},
    {type: "AV", "1": 4},
    {type: "CD", "9": 2}
]
```

help me please to solve this thankyou

Comment: Show your solutions. And what were the problems?

Comment: i still cant grouping my data by type and add key day as new key in dict output as i expect  in question above , cant you help me please to get it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the build-on function on python lib `from itertools import groupby`
it will give you the output that you want. you can do with normal for abuy this is  my version on short for
example:

```
result = [{"type": key, **{str(d["day"]): d["total"] for d in group} } for key, group in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x["type"])]
```